# My objective is to create an application that uses getter and setter methods to add or subtract 2 numbers, I have hit a brick wall

Tags: java

I keep receiving an error when compiling (./Calculator Java32 &36 missing return statement) I am having difficulty seeing where my code is broken, Im new to java(that goes without saying im sure) any help would be appreciated. Thank You.

```
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    public class CalculatorTestDrive
    {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {


   int user = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "If you would like to Add enter 1 or if you would like to Subtract enter 2"));
   while((user == 1)||(user == 2))
   {
   int a = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please Enter Your First Number"));
   int b = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please Enter Your Second Number"));
   Calculator one = new Calculator();

   one.setFirstnumber(a);
   one.setSecondnumber(b);
   }
   }
   }

public class Calculator
{

    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int z;
    int userImput1;
    int userImput2;
    int add = 1;
    int subtract = 2;
    int user;
    public void add()
    {
        z = x + y;
    }
    public void subtract()
    {
        z = x - y;
    }
    public int getFirstnumber()
    {
        return  x;
    }
    public int getSecondnumber()
    {
        return  y;
    }

    public int setFirstnumber(int userImput1)
    {
        x = userImput1;
    }
    public int setSecondnumber(int userImput2)
    {
        y = userImput2;
    }

}
```

Comment: The last 2 methodes do not have a return statement. They should be "void" since a setter usually does not return anything.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `void` as return type when you are not going to return anything, as usual for setter-methods:

```
public void setFirstnumber(int userImput1)
{
    x = userImput1;
}
public void setSecondnumber(int userImput2)
{
    y = userImput2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void setFirstnumber(int userImput1)
{
    x = userImput1;
}
public void setSecondnumber(int userImput2)
{
    y = userImput2;
}
```